# AWS lex nested slots

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, amazon-lex

can one slot depend on another slots result

lets say I have an intent "illness" and utterances "I was sick"

first slot asks "are you ok now?" 
second slot based on first slots result should behave differently

for example

-I was sick (user)

-are you ok now? (bot)

**1 scenario**
-yes (user)

-nice, lets do some workout (bot)

**2 scenario.**
-No (user)

-Sorry to hear you're not feeling better, are you going to do today's workout? (bot)

-No (user)

-Okay, but don't put it off too long!(bot)

How to make nested slots? Is it possible at all?
Does aws lex good for such apps?

Comment: The logic handling of building responses based on what the user says is exactly what Lex is good for. But you need to use a Lambda Function and write the code for handling it yourself. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/gs2-prepare.html

Answer (score 0):

From the information here, I understand you want to create follow-up questions.
This cannot be done using the general functionalities of Lex, but you can create a AWS Lambda function for fulfilment. Create slots for every question you want to ask and constantly return "ElicitSlot" action to simulate follow-up questions.
I agree, AWS Lex is not the best framework for this conversational model, but it can be modified by using it alongside Lambda.